# Store Procedure error in Free Webhosting at Biz.nf

Tags: php, stored-procedures, web-hosting

Since I'm doing the web hosting first time so i randomly picked the biz.nf domain for my web hosting.
i had perfectly upload my php pages and other resource over the ftp but when i tried to import my database it giving me store procedure error.

these all are my store procedures

https://jumpshare.com/v/t16ooSo6c4wgpANBtr6E?b=jtcHudXwZxSTZGj3CmfN

the biz.bf database was giving the error that you don't have Super user privilege so i tried to change the root with my free web host username and localhost with my host of domain but it didn't work for me at all after that i remove that part DEFINER=root@localhost and then all the store procedure execute correctly but when i m trying to call them from sql or via php 
my database giving me the error that 'faana final'.pviewapplicants not in scope. now i don't know any way how to call them.